# UITabBarController customisation page top bar colour swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, customization

How do I change the colour of the top bar of the customisation page of the more view controller. Please see the linked image. Sorry I can't post image here because of my low reputation.

[Screenshot Image](http://s16.postimg.org/y8l4xfhpx/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Jun_7_2015_7_17_07_P.png)

**Edited with more info:**

I have managed to change the background color using the following code. But cant change the color of the top bar.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, willBeginCustomizingViewControllers viewControllers: [AnyObject]) {

    var editView : UIView = tabBarController.view.subviews[1] as! UIView
    editView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basically 2 Ways you can achieve this if you are using Global Unique colour in the app for All navigation bar**

Use this Solution on App Launch:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

**Or if you want to change the Color of More navigationcontroller only then**

Use this Solution by getting the Tabbar Reference :

```
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

*You can use second solution in the First viewcontroller of the Tab, because that contains your tabbar reference*

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. Your second solution changes the bar color of the moreviewcontroller not the customization view.

Comment: Your first method works. But I cant use that because I am using different bar color for other parts of app and this changes universally

Comment: @kmakma so is your problem solve now ? or still you not able to achieve the solution.

Comment: @kmakma oh I got now what you are referring

Comment: no its still not solved because I cant cant change the Global navigation bar color since i am using different colors in my other views. Using the second method you have suggested, it changes the color of the morenavigationcontroller but not the customization view which I want to change.